# "Rails s" has abruptly stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was getting a bit frustrated with a project I have been working on for the past few days, so I decided to make a little blog for fun (and practice). I created the new rails application and tried to boot it up with “rails s”, but it didn’t work. Confused, I went back to my last project, started the server there, went to localhost:3000 like I have been for the past 2 months, but then ran into the same issue. It had been working 5 minutes earlier, but now neither it, nor any other projects will start.

Here is what I see in the command prompt:


```
C:\Users\mathi_000\Desktop\fPen\rails s
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting WEBrick 
=> Rails 4.1.8 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000 
=> Run ‘rails server –h’ for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider
  using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
```

When I go to localhost:3000, I am met with the "This page can't be displayed" message. Hopefully one of you can tell me what I screwed up! I am still in the process of learning, but this is obviously a rather large hindrance.

Comment: What's is show in the log when this happens?

Comment: Might need some more details to get this one solved.  On first glance, it seems the application is running without error.  Can you telnet to the port via command line?

Answer (score 2):

There's not much to go on here, but give my standard solution to these sorts of problems a go: `spring stop` then try again.